# resolving promise from another function

Tags: angular, typescript, promise

How does promise chaining inside a function works?
In the following code:

```
     promiseA() {
            return anotherPromise().then( res => {
                   // resolution of promise A
             })
     };


      promiseB() {
             promiseA().then( res => {
                     // resolution of promise B
              })
      }
```

I tested this code and I get that resolution of B is always done after A is resolved. However, I can't find any documentation. Will resolution of promise B always happens after resolution of Promise A done, or is my test just one case of race condition?

Comment: It doesn't matter if there are functions or not. `then` means that it will be executed after promise resolution.

Comment: so in this case, is A resolved first and then B? @estus

Comment: Yes, that's the purpose of `then`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it will always resolve A first before B. If you re-wrote your code without the indirection of separate methods what you have is simply:

```
anotherPromise().then(...A...).then(...B...)
```

And that should make it clear that the code inside the A `then` *must* always run before the code inside the B `then`.

A simple test confirms. You can run this a million times and A will always resolve before B:

```js
function anotherPromise(){
  return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
   setTimeout(resolve,1000);
  });
}

function promiseA(){
   return anotherPromise().then( res => {
      console.log("Resolve promiseA");
      return res;
  });
}

function promiseB(){
    return promiseA().then(res => {
     console.log("Resolve promiseB");
      return res;
    })
}

promiseB();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have invoked the Promise A inside Promise B, so by logic Promise A should be resolved before Promise B.

```
Promise.then( // resolved first )
       .then( // resolved second )
```